# Insert blob in oracle database with C#

Tags: c#, oracle, tdd

I have to persist a .csv in my database, but for a more testable application I prefer don't use procedures.
Basically I just generate a file and the next instruction is put this in database.

Someone have some clue about best way to do this in code?

Comment: For clarification, are you looking for the SQL string for inserting the BLOB or, the C# datatype to use when handling BLOB data? If the later, I believe its a byte array.

Comment: You should use **Oracle Data Provider for .NET** in your C# project. There are many of useful classes with all needed functionality. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

Comment: Garotão: http://blog.calyptus.eu/seb/2009/03/large-object-storage-for-nhibernate-and-ddd-part-1-blobs-clobs-and-xlobs/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is an example to insert blob data in oracle using c# and procedures (you said prefer that means you may).

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

//Step 1
// Connect to database
// Note: Modify User Id, Password, Data Source as per your database setup
string constr = "User Id=Scott;Password=tiger;Data Source=orcl9i";

OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);
con.Open();
Console.WriteLine("Connected to database!");

// Step 2
// Note: Modify the Source and Destination location
// of the image as per your machine settings
String SourceLoc  = "D:/Images/photo.jpg";
String DestinationLoc = "D:/Images/TestImage.jpg";

// provide read access to the file

FileStream fs = new FileStream(SourceLoc, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);

// Create a byte array of file stream length
byte[] ImageData = new byte[fs.Length];

//Read block of bytes from stream into the byte array
fs.Read(ImageData,0,System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));

//Close the File Stream
fs.Close();

// Step 3
// Create Anonymous PL/SQL block string
String block = " BEGIN " +
               " INSERT INTO testblob (id, photo) VALUES (100, :1); " +
               " SELECT photo into :2 from testblob WHERE id = 100; " +
               " END; ";

// Set command to create Anonymous PL/SQL Block
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.CommandText = block;
cmd.Connection = con;


// Since executing an anonymous PL/SQL block, setting the command type
// as Text instead of StoredProcedure
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

// Step 4
// Setting Oracle parameters

// Bind the parameter as OracleDbType.Blob to command for inserting image
OracleParameter param = cmd.Parameters.Add("blobtodb", OracleDbType.Blob);
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;


// Assign Byte Array to Oracle Parameter
param.Value = ImageData;

// Bind the parameter as OracleDbType.Blob to command for retrieving the image
OracleParameter param2 = cmd.Parameters.Add("blobfromdb", OracleDbType.Blob);
param2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

// Step 5
// Execute the Anonymous PL/SQL Block

// The anonymous PL/SQL block inserts the image to the
// database and then retrieves the images as an output parameter
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Console.WriteLine("Image file inserted to database from " + SourceLoc);

// Step 6
// Save the retrieved image to the DestinationLoc in the file system

// Create a byte array
byte[] byteData = new byte[0];

// fetch the value of Oracle parameter into the byte array
byteData = (byte[])((OracleBlob)(cmd.Parameters[1].Value)).Value;

// get the length of the byte array
int ArraySize = new int();
ArraySize = byteData.GetUpperBound(0);

// Write the Blob data fetched from database to the filesystem at the
// destination location
FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(@DestinationLoc,
                                FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
fs1.Write(byteData, 0,ArraySize);
fs1.Close();

Console.WriteLine("Image saved to " + DestinationLoc + " successfully !");
Console.WriteLine("");
Console.WriteLine("***********************************************************");
Console.WriteLine("Before running this application again, execute 'Listing 1' ");
```

Comment: I dont have hard coded source location as the file is uploaded by the client. So how can I open that file as I dont have the complete path to open the file with filestream object?

Answer (score 9):

```
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Read Image Bytes into a byte array
            byte[] blob = ReadFile(txtPath.Text);

            //Initialize Oracle Server Connection
            con = new OracleConnection(conString);

            //Set insert query
            string qry = "insert into Imgpn (imgpath,photo) values('" + txtPath.Text + "'," + " :BlobParameter )";
            OracleParameter blobParameter = new OracleParameter();
            blobParameter.OracleType = OracleType.Blob;
            blobParameter.ParameterName = "BlobParameter";
            blobParameter.Value = blob;

            //Initialize OracleCommand object for insert.
            cmd = new OracleCommand(qry, con);

            //We are passing Name and Blob byte data as Oracle parameters.
            cmd.Parameters.Add(blobParameter);

            //Open connection and execute insert query.
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show("Image added to blob field");
            GetImagesFromDatabase();
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Close();
            //this.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
    byte[] ReadFile(string sPath)
    {
        //Initialize byte array with a null value initially.
        byte[] data = null;

        //Use FileInfo object to get file size.
        FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(sPath);
        long numBytes = fInfo.Length;

        //Open FileStream to read file
        FileStream fStream = new FileStream(sPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        //Use BinaryReader to read file stream into byte array.
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fStream);

        //When you use BinaryReader, you need to supply number of bytes to read from file.
        //In this case we want to read entire file. So supplying total number of bytes.
        data = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);
        return data;
    }
    void GetImagesFromDatabase()
    {
        try
        {
            //Initialize Oracle  connection.
            con = new OracleConnection(conString);
            //MessageBox.Show("Connection Successfull");
            //Initialize Oracle adapter.
            OracleDataAdapter oda = new OracleDataAdapter("Select * from Imgpn", con);

            //Initialize Dataset.
            DataSet DS = new DataSet();

            //Fill dataset with ImagesStore table.
            oda.Fill(DS, "Imgpn");

            //Fill Grid with dataset.

            dataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables["Imgpn"];
            //
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

here is the simple way to insert image into oracle database ane retrieve ane show in datagridview

Comment: Should be `.OracleDbType`, not `.OracleType`, on `blobParameter`.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.troyhunt.com/2013/07/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-sql.html). **NEVER** use string concatenation to build a SQL query. **ALWAYS** use a parameterized query.

Comment: `BinaryReader` is `IDisposable`. It should be used in a `using` block.