# How to insert document or PDF file into Oracle database using ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, database, oracle, document

I have a `CLOB` data type on my database and a `FileUpload` button on my ASP.Net.  So my question is how can I insert a word document or PDF file into my Oracle database using ASP.Net?

Anyone knows how to do this?  I'm a beginner.  Please bear with me :)

Comment: that depends on how you access the DB... which ADO.NET provider do you use ?

Comment: duplicate see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902250/insert-blob-in-oracle-database-with-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

You'd better separate the question in two parts (for handling file upload, for BLOB I/O) and post again to get more detail answers.

Or, you can search SO with these keywords: FileUpload, BLOB, Oracle (tag .net)

Below are my Google search result about ASP.NET BLOB read/write for Oracle provider:

[Insert /retrieve an image into/ from a blob field in Oracle database using C#.Net](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Blobfield.aspx)

[Writing to Oracle CLOB fields using System.Data.OracleClient](http://weblogs.asp.net/jdanforth/archive/2005/09/06/424513.aspx)

Comment: According to MS `System.Data.OracleClient` is deprecated - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/15/system-data-oracleclient-update.aspx!

Answer (score 0):

UTFG! Search "oracle ado.net clob" in Google and check this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971488.aspx).

Comment: According to MS `System.Data.OracleClient` is deprecated - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/15/system-data-oracleclient-update.aspx!

Comment: But that doesn't mean, you can't use it. Cited: System.Data.OracleClient will be available in the upcoming 4.0 release of .NET Framework; however, it will be marked as deprecated. This will have no impact to existing applications and these applications will continue to work as expected.

Comment: But it means that if you are starting something new then you should really consider avoiding it...

Comment: Ok, but the code will be almost identical - you will just use another data provider.

Comment: Not really... esp. regarding CLOB/BLOB handling there is a difference on how the different providers handle that (some offer means to optimize the memory usage for example)...