# Update CLOB using a textbox in C#

Tags: c#, oracle11g, clob

I've been all over the web with this one and I am surprised how I can't seem to find any way to do what I looking for.

I am using the `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` library in my C# project, **not** the deprecated `System.Data.OracleClient.`

I have a very simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE testing (
      ID NUMBER(10),
      COMMENTS CLOB,
      DATECREATED   DATE DEFAULT (SYSDATE) NOT NULL,
      DATEMODIFIED  DATE
);

INSERT INTO testing (ID, COMMENTS) VALUES(1, 'this is a test');
```

The above obviously works just fine. The problem is, this being a comment field it will be changed. In my C# program I would like to allow users to save comments. For this example I am removing anything complex.

I have a button on a form and a textbox called "comments".

```
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(<VALID CONN STRING GOES HERE>)) {
    connection.Open();
    using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand()) {
         command.Connection = connection;
         command.CommandText = "UPDATE testing SET COMMENTS = :COMMENTS, DATEMODIFIED = sysdate WHERE ID = :ID";
         command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
         command.Parameters.Add("ID", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = 1;
         command.Parameters.Add("COMMENTS", OracleDbType.Clob, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = comments.Text;
         command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

So basically this code works as long as I don't attempt to write the Clob. If I save the date modified is created as expected. However when I save with the Clob, nothing happens. No error message from oracle, no exception, nothing.

If I forgo parameterization and do it the wrong way:

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE testing SET COMMENTS = " + comments.Text + ", DATEMODIFIED = sysdate";
```

There is no problem. It seems the parameterization is the issue here.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902250/insert-blob-in-oracle-database-with-c-sharp

Comment: That question is dealing with the "BLOB" datatype, "CLOB" is generally for characters. Different approach as BLOB might come from a file stream where as mine comes from a textbox.

Comment: Silly problem, it's amazing what lunch and a meeting can do. Should this question get deleted or does it have enough value to help someone in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was correct in that parameterization was the issue, however I can say it was a very basic mistake. Anyway the statement was actually running perfectly fine but the parameters were being added out of order.

Note how in the following code ID is added last, as it is the last parameter (where clause.)

```
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(<VALID CONN STRING GOES HERE>)) {
    connection.Open();
    using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand()) {
         command.Connection = connection;
         command.CommandText = "UPDATE testing SET COMMENTS = :COMMENTS, DATEMODIFIED = sysdate WHERE ID = :ID";
         command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
         command.Parameters.Add("COMMENTS", OracleDbType.Clob, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = comments.Text;
         command.Parameters.Add("ID", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = 1;
         command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this work when the comments.Text.Length > 32k characters? I suspect it won't. This answer is dependent upon an implicit conversion of varchar2 to clob, which breaks down after the PL/SQL maximum length for the varchar2 data type is exceeded.

Comment: That's unfortunate. In my particular implementation the chances of going past 100 characters are unlikely but I'll need to make note of this issue and handle it. Thank you for the info.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the binding out of order for ODP .NET, you need to specify this extra command (better practice)  This was not required if you had previously used Microsoft's provider.

Command.BindByName=true;

Can you test your update with > 32K in the comment to see if it errors?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience an Oracle CLOB can be written to in this context by converting a String to a character array with the following:

```
String input = "string value";

OracleParameter parm = new OracleParameter("parameter_name", OracleDbType.Clob);
parm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
parm.Value = input.toCharArray();
```

as a CLOB is a character large object.