# C# ODBC Insert BLOB

Tags: c#, oracle, insert, odbc, blob

The code below works fine when connecting to a SQL Server, however it throws an exception when I try pointing it to an Oracle database. The exception returns a empty error message, so I'm not really sure what I should look at next. Any help would greatly appreciated. I did search before making this post and all the questions relating to oracle seemed to use the Oracle ADO methods and not ODBC.

Here's the variable setting for the read_blob_file function below:

```
  string dbname = "oracle_odbc_database";
  string uid = "username";
  string pwd = "password";
  string sql = "INSERT INTO CD_ATTACHMENT (\"ATTACHMENT_ID\",\"DESCRIPTION\",\"ATTACHMENT\",\"CREATE_DATE\",\"MIME_TYPE\",\"CREATE_USER_ID\",\"CREATE_APP_ID\",\"UPDATE_DATE\",\"UPDATE_USER_ID\",\"UPDATE_APP_ID\") VALUES (''YPoem'','NULL',?,'to_date('10/8/2013 6:30:41 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')','NULL',''EFPUFC1B(AMERICAS\\EFPUFC1B)'',''OpenWells'','NULL','NULL','NULL');";
  string blob_value = "'c:\\ATTACHMENT\\00AfKOHF-ATTACHMENT.blob'";
  string blob_column = "ATTACHMENT";


private int read_blob_file(string dbname, string uid, string pwd, string sql)
        {
            int rtncmd = -99;
            try
            {
                using (var conn = new OdbcConnection("DSN=" + dbname + ";UID=" + uid + ";pwd=" + pwd))
                {
                    conn.ConnectionTimeout = 1500;
                    conn.Open();
                    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        if (blob_value != "")
                        {
                            blob_value = blob_value.Replace("'","");
                            using (var inputStream = File.OpenRead(blob_value))
                            {
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(blob_column, File.ReadAllBytes(blob_value));
                            }
                        }
                        cmd.CommandText = sql;
                        rtncmd = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            return rtncmd;
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the length of the blob content you are inserting?

Comment: I can try that, but the same blob works with the SQL server, just not with Oracle server.

Comment: I've had weirder experiences with an Oracle database, trust me :)

Comment: Is this of any use? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902250/insert-blob-in-oracle-database-with-c-sharp

Comment: Changing the blob filesize made no difference.  I even changed to X86 in case it was a 32-bit client problem and that didn't change the outcome either.

Comment: Prior to posting here, I had looked at that (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902250/insert-blob-in-oracle-database-with-c-sharp) article, but it's using oracle drivers and not ODBC.